Can't insert data to mongoDB if it's an Object type
I'm exporting data from an API to JSON files and importing them to MongoDB. My problem is that if I have an Object within the document I can't write data to that Object and I can't find what is causing the problem. From what I've read it's possible to use Object type in a Schema but I can't find a working solution, instead I have to completely restructure the JSON file to not include Objects.
Reconfigured everything from scratch multiple times, tried looking for solutions all over the internet but no luck.
This is my Schema
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const phoneSchema = new Schema({
   
id:{type: String, required:false},
data:{
    key:{type: String, required: false},
    device_name:{type: String, required: false},
    display_size:{type: String, required: false},
    display_res:{type: String, required: false},
    camera:{type: String, required: false},
    video:{type: String, required: false},
    ram:{type: String, required: false},
    chipset:{type: String, required: false},
    battery:{type: String, required: false},
    batteryType:{type: String, required: false},
    release_date:{type: String, required: false},
    body:{type: String, required: false},
    os_type:{type: String, required: false},
    storage:{type: String, required: false},
    comment:{type: String, required: false},
    pictures: {type: Array, required: false}
}
});

When I run the following, only the "id" is inserted and nothing else. What am I missing?
const iphone13p = new Phone ({key:"apple_iphone_13_pro", os_type:"iOS17",storage:"512GB", id:"i13p"});
iphone13p.save();


Oh, and I almost forgot. I tried data.key: , data.os_type: , etc. but it doesn't work.
I'm really new to these things, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

The fields except to the id should be into the data object like: const iphone13p = new Phone ({data: {key:"apple_iphone_13_pro", os_type:"iOS17",storage:"512GB"}, id:"i13p"}); 

Yes, it's working! I'm very new to this field of work and I can easily make these kinds of mistakes. Thank you for your help!

Yes, it is so usual to make some mistakes like these at the beginning. You're welcome, good luck!
